# Wait for radio change

Tags: java, wait

Okay so what I am trying to do is wait for the user to select a different selection and hit the continue button before the program reads his/her answer.

Currently the program doesn't wait for for the user to change their answer and hit the "Choose" button.

It doesnt change the option text yet it will be different road names

Currently i have this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ContainerEvent;
import java.awt.event.ContainerListener;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class GameScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener, ContainerListener {

    static String classString;
    static int classInt = 0; // 1- wiz 2-warr 3-arch 4-lock  
    static int option;

    public static void classStore() throws IOException {

    FileWriter classChose = new FileWriter("classChose.txt");
    System.out.print(classInt);
    System.out.print(classString);
    classChose.write(classString);
    classChose.close();
    start.setVisible(true);

    }
    public GameScreen() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jPopupMenu1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        info = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        opt1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        opt2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        opt3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        opt4 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        optionOneText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        optionTwoText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        optionThreeText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        optionFourText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        classButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        optionButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        start = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        info.setColumns(20);
        info.setRows(5);
        info.setText("Welcome. Please choose a class.");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(info);

        buttonGroup1.add(opt1);
        opt1.setText("Option One");

        buttonGroup1.add(opt2);
        opt2.setText("Option Two");

        buttonGroup1.add(opt3);
        opt3.setText("Option Three");

        buttonGroup1.add(opt4);
        opt4.setText("Option Four");

        optionOneText.setEditable(false);
        optionOneText.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        optionOneText.setText("Wizard");

        optionTwoText.setEditable(false);
        optionTwoText.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        optionTwoText.setText("Warrior");

        optionThreeText.setEditable(false);
        optionThreeText.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        optionThreeText.setText("Archer");

        optionFourText.setEditable(false);
        optionFourText.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        optionFourText.setText("Warlock");

        classButton.setText("Choose");
        classButton.addActionListener(this);

        jButton2.setText("Exit");
        jButton2.addActionListener(this);

        optionButton.setText("Choose");
        optionButton.setEnabled(false);
        optionButton.addContainerListener(this);
        optionButton.addActionListener(this);

        start.setText("Begin");
        start.addActionListener(this);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                .addComponent(classButton)
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addComponent(optionButton)
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addComponent(start)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(opt3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(optionThreeText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 302, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(opt4)
                    .addComponent(opt2)
                    .addComponent(opt1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(optionFourText)
                    .addComponent(optionOneText)
                    .addComponent(optionTwoText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 115, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(opt1)
                    .addComponent(optionOneText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(opt2)
                    .addComponent(optionTwoText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(opt3)
                    .addComponent(optionThreeText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(opt4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(optionFourText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 10, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(classButton)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(optionButton)
                    .addComponent(start))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == classButton) {
            GameScreen.this.classButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == jButton2) {
            GameScreen.this.jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == start) {
            GameScreen.this.startActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == optionButton) {
            GameScreen.this.optionButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    }

    public void componentAdded(java.awt.event.ContainerEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == optionButton) {
            GameScreen.this.optionButtonComponentAdded(evt);
        }
    }

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.exit(0);
    }                                        

    private void classButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        //Check option
        while (classInt < 1)
        {
        if (opt1.isSelected())
        {
         classString = "Wizard";
         classInt = 1;
         optionButton.setVisible(true);
         classButton.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if (opt2.isSelected())
        {
        classString = "Warrior";
         classInt = 2;
         optionButton.setVisible(true);
         classButton.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(opt3.isSelected())
        {
            classString = "Archer";
         classInt = 3;
         optionButton.setVisible(true);
         classButton.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(opt4.isSelected())
        {
            classString = "Warlock";
         classInt = 4;
         optionButton.setVisible(true);
         classButton.setVisible(false);
        }
        else
        {
        info.setText("Please select a class below.");
        }

            break;
        }
        try {
            buttonGroup1.clearSelection();
            classStore();
            info.setText("You have chosen to be an: " + classString);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GameScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                           

    private void optionButtonComponentAdded(java.awt.event.ContainerEvent evt) {                                            
        optionButton.setVisible(false);
    }                                           

    private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        start.setVisible(false);
        optionButton.setEnabled(true);

        wizardStory();

    }                                     

    private void optionButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        //Check option
        if (opt1.isSelected())
        {option = 1;

        }
        else if (opt2.isSelected())
            option = 2;
        else if (opt3.isSelected())
            option = 3;
        else 
            option = 4;


    }     
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GameScreen().setVisible(true);
                optionButton.setVisible(false);
                start.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }
    public int getOption()
    {
    optionButton.isSelected();
    optionButton.isEnabled();
    return option;
    }
    public void wizardStory()
    {
    info.setText("This is where your story begins.\nPlease select the road you wish to travel.");

    if (option == 1)
    {
        info.setText("Didn't work.");
        System.out.print("didnt work");
    }
    else if (option == 2)
    {
        info.setText("Did work.");
        System.out.print("worked");
    }
    }                 
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JButton classButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea info;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu jPopupMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton opt1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton opt2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton opt3;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton opt4;
    public static javax.swing.JButton optionButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField optionFourText;
    private javax.swing.JTextField optionOneText;
    private javax.swing.JTextField optionThreeText;
    private javax.swing.JTextField optionTwoText;
    private static javax.swing.JButton start;
    @Override
    public void componentRemoved(ContainerEvent ce) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }              
}
```

Comment: 1) From `optionButtonActionPerformed` call `wizardStory()` 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I could do that but wizard story is going to be expanded and i have 4 classes so i want to add something that i can call when i need to make a chose.

Comment: *"i want to add something that i can call when i need to make a chose."*  Yes, that is exactly what the Action Performed method is doing.

Comment: Can you show your form? what exactly you have in your option's selected event? you need to override all the event methods for radio button and keep them empty only then your form wont get submitted. also what is getOption() method doing?

Comment: @SandiipPatil *"Can you show your form?"*  More than a 1/4 hour ago, I suggested the OP post an SSCCE that would have shown that.  They seem to be ignoring me.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Sorry I'm new to the site I've been trying to figure out how to produce an SSCCE.

Comment: Andrew has given you the link for SSCCE, use that. We need to see your input form code in order to get the problem. you can edit your question and post the form code

Comment: @AndrewThompson  I think i got it now sorry for the confusion and thank you for the help so far I just finished my first gui game two days ago and am trying to expand my abilities.

Comment: The code in your edit is not an SSCCE.  It does not compile as copy/pasted, therefore it cannot be an SSCCE of a run-time problem.

Comment: *"Is SSCCE a program?"*  Did you read the linked document?  What in it do you not understand?

Comment: @AndrewThompson After 10 mins of fighting the <Code> blocks i think i got it.

Comment: This code violates at least one of the S in SSCCE.

Comment: @Dahaka Sorry fixed it.

Comment: Most people (me included) would not consider 362 lines as 'short'.  OTOH - A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough!

Comment: Sorry...again... I took all the excess whitespace and some comments out. Down to 320ish lines.

Answer (score 0):

GUI's are event driven environments.  That is, unlike a console program where, typically, the program moves from one sequence of instructions to another, GUI's "wait" for some kind of event to occur and then respond to those events.

In Swing, you don't actually need to wait, this is taken care for you.  What you need to be able to do, is respond to appropriate events as they occur.

Take a closer look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details.

The basic idea for you would be to devise some way that you could 1- put the options one the screen and 2- respond to the `actionEvent` when it occurs and update the state of the program when it does.

Comment: Is there a way to tell my wizardStory (and eventually my other class methods) method to wait for a button press by using listeners?

Comment: You can't "wait", you can only react.  You need to change your way of thinking.  Present your options, attach a listener and handle the events when they occur.  Make appropriate choices about the direction the next stage of your program needs to take and repeat